# Regular Expression for Ruby gsub! with anchor that should not match

Tags: ruby, regex

The following regular expression should work in Ruby, but it doesn't.
Any ideas on how to fix it, so it can be used in a `.gsub!` statement in a loop?

```
textfield.gsub!( /(http:\/\/){0}www\./, 'http://www.' )
```

`{0}` should allow to match the first part zero times, but it does not:

```
'http://www.company1.com
 http://www.company2.com'.gsub!( /(http:\/\/){0}www\./, 'http://www.' )
```

=> "http://http://www.company1.com
     http://http://www.company2.com

**in this example the regexp should not match, and leave the input string unmodified!**

any ideas on how to make this work?

this looks like a bug in Ruby's regexp processing

I admit that I'm trying to generously interpret the semantics of `{n}` to include `n = 0` :)

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: in the example, it should not match the input string, and leave it unmodified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to make the capturing group as optional.

```
> 'http://www.example.com'.gsub(/(http:\/\/)?www\./, 'http://www.')
=> "http://www.example.com"
> 'www.example.com'.gsub(/(http:\/\/)?www\./, 'http://www.')
=> "http://www.example.com"
```

`(http:\/\/)?` matches the string `http://` zero or one times.

**OR**

You could use negative lookbehind also.

```
> 'www.example.com'.gsub(/(?<!http:\/\/)www\./, 'http://www.')
=> "http://www.example.com"
```

Here the substitution should happen because the string `www.` isn't preceded by `http://`.

```
> 'http://www.example.com'.gsub(/(?<!http:\/\/)www\./, 'http://www.')
=> "http://www.example.com"
```

Here the substitution won't happen because the string `www.` is preceded by `http://`. So the interpreter returns the original input string without any modifications.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that `/(http:\/\/){0}/` matches the start of any string. In fact, `/(x){0}/` will match the start of any string for any value of `x`. This regular expression says that we should find `x` zero times. Well, we can find `x` zero times between any two characters.

What you want is the start-of-string character, `^`, followed by a negative lookahead assertion, `(?!...)`. This allows you to match strings that do not begin with a particular sequence of characters.

```
'http://www.example.com'.gsub(/^(?!http:\/\/)www\./, 'http://www.')
# => 'http://www.example.com'

'www.example.com'.gsub(/^(?!http:\/\/)www\./, 'http://www.')
# => 'http://www.example.com'
```

Comment: excellent point! didn't think of that it would match any beginning of string - duh! :)  This needs Negative Lookbehind